# Jar conflict issue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, websphere

I am using aws sdk package to access aws api from web application deployed in a websphere application. During build the application doesn't throws any compile time issue. After deployment it throws **java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE**

I read some post, it says about jar conflict. Its taking the default httpclient jars from IBM. I want to point my code to take my version of httpclient which I have given in lib folder. Can someone help me to point my code to pick my version of jars added manually.

Comment: This is what happens when you develop with one code base and deploy to another. The larger answer is need to be using the same code base for development and deployment.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thanks for replying, this is caused by websphere server, i am using same code base. In websphere I want to point my app to app lib instead of parent library from IBM server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make your app use its own version of something that's included in the server, you'll need to use parent-last class loader delegation. Assuming the Apache HTTP client is in your web module's WEB-INF/lib directory, you'll want to make that change to the web module's class loader setting (this doc is specifically from 8.5.5 but should work on any version from the last decade or so): https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=loading-configuring-web-module-class-loaders

Note that parent-last delegation comes with its own set of risks, as there are some things that don't play well with the server if you try and use a version in your app (the Servlet API is one of the more notable ones). If you try this but run into things like ClassCastExceptions or LinkageErrors, you may instead want to put the HTTP client into an isolated shared library (selecting the "use an isolated class loader for this shared library" option) and associate the shared library with your web module or application: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=servers-managing-shared-libraries

All that said, the simplest solution might just be to update your server. An APAR several years ago (PI50993, included in fixpack 8.5.5.9) removed the application visibility to the server's version of the Apache HTTP client. Moving to a recent fixpack would probably resolve the issue as well.

Comment: Even after changing the option to parent-last class loader delegation, I am getting similar kind of issues **java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE**

Comment: I am getting this issue 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory (initialization failure)

Comment: Did you set the parent-last class loading delegation on the application, or the web module? You have to set it at the specific scope that contains the version of the HTTP jars that you need - if the jar is in WEB-INF/lib in your WAR, you'll need to set it on the web module; if it's a /lib directory in the EAR, you'll need to set it on the application.

Comment: The "(initialization failure)" in that NoClassDefFoundError means that the root cause was some other exception, occurring in the static initializer of SdkTLSSocketFactory. Unless that root exception was the same NoSuchFieldError, it's probably outside the scope of this specific question.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have created an isolated shared library and pointed  it to the application war in websphere server, it worked no conflict happened.